# Need help in writing a Receipt Printer driver for the Epson POS TM-T88 on iOS devices(iPhone, iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, printing, point-of-sale

I write an native application for an iOS devices(iPhone and iPad) and want to print to Receipt Printer Epson TM-T88. I can not find any information on how to write a driver for Receipt Printer on iOS devices. Pleas can some one help me out or point out where even to start, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Epson provides SDKs for iOS, which should be sufficient in connecting to their printers.

http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/index.htm

I don't believe the T88 is supported unless you have the Ethernet module to give the printer a TCP/IP connection as I believe that is the only way to print through iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The target printer needs to be "AirPrint" capable. Currently, only a handful of HP printers are capable. I recommend you looking into solutions similar to [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/).

Comment: I know about "AirPrint" in iOS 4.2, but it is steel posable to write your own print drivers(i just don't know where to start), you can fined lots of examples in google or youtube when app on iPhone prints directly to an receipt printer

Comment: Are you hoping to connect the device to the printer as an external accessory? If that's the case you'll need to get specifications for the Epson TM-T88 so you'll know what to send to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do this too but this is all I can find on StackOveflow:

[Printing to Epson TM-T88V receipt printer from iOS/iPad using CUPS or other framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892760/printing-to-epson-tm-t88v-receipt-printer-from-ios-ipad-using-cups-or-other-fram)

[Why can I not receive a response from a TCP/IP capable printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652694/why-can-i-not-receive-a-response-from-a-tcp-ip-capable-printer)

[printing from ipad to receipt printer(Epson TM-T88v) thr wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003136/printing-from-ipad-to-receipt-printerepson-tm-t88v-thr-wifi)

The 3rd post mentions signing up with [Epson Expert](https://www.epsonexpert.com/login.htm) to gain access to technical docs etc. The TM-T88 Technical Reference Guide states:

> With ESC/POS commands, you can
>   directly control all the TM printer functions, but detailed knowledge of printer specifications or 
>   combination of commands is required, compared to using a driver.
>   To use ESC/POS commands, you need to agree to a nondisclosure contract first and obtain the 
>   ESC/POS Application Programming Guide. Ask your dealer for details.

It also says this about the TM-T88V Mac Printer Driver:

> Mac printer driver allows you to control the TM-T88V  using Common
>   UNIX Printing System (CUPS) on Mac  OS X.

This MacWorld forum post contains a lot of information about IOS printing via CUPS:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101027080807322