# Why can I not receive a response from a TCP/IP capable printer?

Tags: http, printing, tcp, epson, lpr

My ultimate goal is to send a print job to a printer over the internet. The catch is that the printer is connected directly to a router, so I can't count on a computer processing anything.

The path a print job takes is: Computer -> Internet -> Router -> Printer

The printer is an Epson TM-T88V with the UB-E02 connect it module (it originally came with the 25-pin module).

The router is a D-Link DIR-655 with port 9500 redirected to LAN port 9100 and the LAN IP address of the printer. With this setup, I can enter the router's WAN IP address + port 9500 in a web browser and the printer spits out the HTTP request it receives.

From the terminal, if I use lpr (specifically lpr -h ip-address:9500 filename.txt), the printer prints the HTTP request it receives (not the file) and lpr appears to just be waiting for a response. According to the UB-E02 Technical Reference Guide, the Connect-It module supports lp/lpr.

Why is it that the printer prints the HTTP request and doesn't send a response back?

Comment: Sorry I have to "answer" the post since I can't comment now (new account). Did you have to install any driver for your printer? What device are you printing from? I am trying the same thing on an iPad. Not sure if I need to install any driver.

Comment: No worries. I ended up setting up a central print server that receives print jobs from the iPad over the internet and forwards them to the appropriate printer. It _should_ be safer this way (with port knocking and etc). If you can set up printing over the internet with a computer, then you'll be able to write a script that uses lpr to forward the print job from the iPad to the printer.  On the router connected to the printer, I had to forward an external port to internal port 515. So ip + port number = forwarded print job. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to connect a iOS device to a printer which is on another subnet. As the discussion may be bit long and as there is no place to continue talks here so can I talk to you over mail or facebook or linkedIn ? My email is "rppatnayak54@gmail.com" and you can find me on facebook n linkedIn with id "rameswar54".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port you opened is likely the raw data dump port for the printer.  Likely there is a seperate port which speaks [RFC1179](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1179.txt) that will speak to your `lpr` client.

You should not be sending HTTP control to either of these ports.

Comment: Forwarding port 515 was the key. Now I can print over the internet. Thanks!

Comment: Do be careful, LPD is not an authenticating protocol and someone could print lots of full-black pages with little effort and waste lots of your resources.  May want to wrap with SSH or a port-knocking `lpr`.