# Printing to Epson TM-T88V receipt printer from iOS/iPad using CUPS or other framework

Tags: ios, printing, cups

Does anyone know how to get `CUPS` running on `iOS`? We are trying to print to a networked `Epson` receipt printer ( `TM-T88V`) from the iPad, using `CUPS` or other method but we are running into a brickwall getting CUPS to run on iOS. I know for a fact that this can be done, as an iPad app can already do it just by passing in the IP address of the printer. How are they doing this?

Comment: UPDATE: looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652694/why-can-i-not-receive-a-response-from-a-tcp-ip-capable-printer, it appears you can connect directly to the printer using LPR/LPD on port 515, but I dont know how to use the LPR/LPD protocol from iOS. Is there a library for this?
Also, I can send raw data to port 9100 on the device (from putty.exe on windows) and it will print whatever I type

Comment: Did you how can i scan printers that connect with Ethernet via Epos SDK . i don't know how to find or scan via ethernet connection i have only knowledge about Bluetooth so please help .

Comment: @looselycoupled Have you had any chance to find out how it works? I wanted to do the same thing but I'm kind of stuck, is there any library for doing this? or any document that I can follow. It would be great if you can help me with this.