# printing from ipad to receipt printer(Epson TM-T88v) thr wifi

Tags: ipad

need help in connecting and printing  from ipad  to receipt printer(Epson TM-T88v) thr wifi network?
what are steps to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use ESC/POS commands over a TCP socket.  Epson's documents on ESC/POS require an NDA; you can find them at http://www.epsonexpert.com .